# how to create an applet parallel to a process to show progress

Tags: java, process, applet

i want to create a applet which paints a running ball while a process a running in the Java application . I have no idea how to synch the process time with the applet life . Help please ??

Comment: What do you mean by applet? Do you want to display the applet in a browser while the background task is running on the server? If so this question is too broad to be answered. If you just want to display a progress panel on an existing Java GUI then it is possible that that could be answered.

Comment: The is prohibitively vague, what part are you stuck on?  Running a background process? Painting the ball? Updating the progress from the process to the appelt?

Comment: Put a `JProgressBar` in the application with the long running process.  There are probably ways to do what you actually want, but they are not the 'path of least surprise' to the end user, so just **..don't** do that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831) on which the OP seems unwilling or incapable of explaining the actual use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applets run in a browser controlled JVM, that is completely separate from the JVM executing your program, but can do anything a normal Java application can do.

Therefore the problem here is actually, how you can have one JVM ask another JVM for information and you have several options depending on your need and skills.

I would suggest you look into JMX which is usually used for these kind of things, and if inapplicable then the EndPoint class which provide a tiny web server to your application.